# List of arrays without brackets

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given a list of arrays in this format:

```
[array([[63371.29484043],
    [65000.        ],
    [51114.1118643 ],
    [39000.        ],
    [61549.2893635 ],
    [58204.43242583]]), array([[28750.        ],
    [19166.90102574],
    [19667.19108884],
    [17250.        ]]), array([[32188.01786071],
    [33625.        ],
    [23988.53674308],
    [29354.92883394],
    [31657.26571235],
    [20175.        ]])]`
```

I would like to print it as a list without square brackets in it e.g.

```
a = [18758.98675732, 23418.72996313 ... 20134.77503711]
```

I can apply `.tolist` but not strip to get rid of the inner brackets.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is called [flattening](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) the array.

Comment: `list(a[:,0])` gives `[18758.98675732, 23418.72996313, etc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to understand the nature of the object before worrying too much about display details.  Display follows from the list's structure.  Pay special attention to `len` (for a list) and `shape` (for an array).

```
In [119]: alist=[np.array([[63371.29484043], 
     ...:     [65000.        ], 
     ...:     [51114.1118643 ], 
     ...:     [39000.        ], 
     ...:     [61549.2893635 ], 
     ...:     [58204.43242583]]), np.array([[28750.        ], 
     ...:     [19166.90102574], 
     ...:     [19667.19108884], 
     ...:     [17250.        ]]), np.array([[32188.01786071], 
     ...:     [33625.        ], 
     ...:     [23988.53674308], 
     ...:     [29354.92883394], 
     ...:     [31657.26571235], 
     ...:     [20175.        ]])]
```

You have a list of arrays that differ in shape:

```
In [120]: len(alist)                                                                                         
Out[120]: 3
In [121]: [x.shape for x in alist]                                                                           
Out[121]: [(6, 1), (4, 1), (6, 1)]
```

You could flatten each array, producing ones that a (6,),(4,) and (6,) shape:

```
In [122]: [x.ravel() for x in alist]                                                                         
Out[122]: 
[array([63371.29484043, 65000.        , 51114.1118643 , 39000.        ,
        61549.2893635 , 58204.43242583]),
 array([28750.        , 19166.90102574, 19667.19108884, 17250.        ]),
 array([32188.01786071, 33625.        , 23988.53674308, 29354.92883394,
        31657.26571235, 20175.        ])]
```

`hstack` can join them into on array.  Use `.tolist()` if you want a list as the final result:

```
In [123]: np.hstack(_)                                                                                       
Out[123]: 
array([63371.29484043, 65000.        , 51114.1118643 , 39000.        ,
       61549.2893635 , 58204.43242583, 28750.        , 19166.90102574,
       19667.19108884, 17250.        , 32188.01786071, 33625.        ,
       23988.53674308, 29354.92883394, 31657.26571235, 20175.        ])
```

Since the arrays differ in the first dimension, we could also use:

```
In [127]: np.vstack(alist).shape                                                                             
Out[127]: (16, 1)
In [128]: np.vstack(alist).ravel()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to get the first number of each sublist and flatten the array, then turn it into a list with `list`:

```
list(map(lambda l : l[0], a))
```

Output:

```
[18758.98675732, 23418.72996313, 23625.0, 14175.0, 21015.48300191, 20134.77503711]
```

You can also use numpy's multidimensional array indexing to extract only the first number of each sublist:

```
list(a[:, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has built-in flatten function:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html

```py
list(a[0].ravel())
```

Comment: Use ravel. It won't copy the data unnecessarily

Comment: Are you applying `flatten/ravel` to the list or to the arrays in the list?

Comment: But I thought the request was to get out of numpy too - ravel won't provide that... I will add ravel, I may got it wrong ...

Comment: Gotcha now @MadPhysicist - didn't know ```ravel()``` before, thanks!

Comment: Returns the following error message: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ravel'

Comment: Try now, sorry didn't see most outer brackets. - I thought it's numpy on the outside.